# React JS Convert Function Argument to Reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problems to converting argument to reference

```
changeMenu=()=>{
  //Working code 
  scrollToComponent(this.Info);
}
```

But how to do like this

```
changeMenu=(value)=>{
  console.log(value) // Info
  scrollToComponent(this.value);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? Please elaborate your problem .. where is the React code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do it like this:

```
changeMenu(value) {
  scrollToComponent(this[value]);
}

// Call it like this
this.changeMenu('Info');
```